# UITextView give slow response for appear the keyboard and edit the text view every time

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode, uitextview

When I load the text view with more than 1000 text length for the first time and click on the text view for edit text, keyboard will appear very slowly and text editing also works slowly. But, it's working fine when I load the the text view with less text length.

I am using: iOS 10
, Xcode 8

[image: This is the screenshot and the text come from other view controller]

Comment: Its working fine for me, I tried with 3K words.
can you tell me the exact problem.

Comment: how do you load the texts? can you show us some snapshots?

Comment: @AbhishekSharma check the screenshot

Comment: @nferocious76 check the screenshot

Comment: Have you checked on real device?

Comment: It should not happen.
I am not sure why it's happening. Do you have a list of notes and when you are clicking on the list element? And going to next page you are facing the issue there?

Comment: @KAR also give slow response on real device.

Comment: @AbhishekSharma Yes, Exactly, I am going to next page and facing the issue.

Comment: On the list page, you are loading the complete content(3559 words). and just sending to the data to next page from the list via Segue?

Comment: @AbhishekSharma yes, exactly

Comment: Do one thing
On the list page do not load whole text from DB or API.
Just get 100 or 200 words from DB and API and Show on the list.
On the next page when you are showing your notes. Load the complete data from DB or API. You are loading complete data on list page which is making your view slower.
Try it and let me know

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133267/discussion-between-saurabh-jain-and-abhishek-sharma).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long RnD I found the solution:

This is the iOS 10 issue, the keyboard is hanging in iOS 10 and give slow response.

So I download the swift keyboard from App store and change the default keyboard to swift keyboard. Everything working fine and the text view not give the slow response.

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7230183?start=0&tstart=0
https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7668682?start=0&tstart=0

Comment: Please stop spamming dozens of answers with comments asking about "MDM Usage Time". If you have a question, *ask it*.